# facebook me/home not displaying data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Hey all i am trying to get a news feed (home feed) but this doesnt seem to work:

```
<?php
require '../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'fileUpload' => true,
  'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile   = $facebook->api('/me');
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();    
    $feed           = $facebook->api('/me/home?access_token=' . $access_token);
    print_r($feed);

etc etc....
```

If i comment out the **$feed** and also **print_r($feed)** line then it works and displays my user information. However, leaving it un-commented out seems to stop it from proceeding to display other things.

I have also tried:

```
$feed           = $facebook->api('/me/home);
```

and that still produces nothing.

For my **app center permissions**, i have set the permissions needed to do this (read_stream) among others.

What am i missing?

[image]

Comment: Your 'app center permissions' apply only to users who authorise your app for the first time via your App Details Page - you need to explicitly request the scopes you want for all other users and entry points to your app - are you doing that?

Comment: Where do i put the scope at in my code then? I figured that just having it within the apps settings is all that was needed when the user accepted it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it was due to me not having this:

```
$statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
$params = array(
    'scope' => 'read_stream'
);
```

Worked after i added that! :o)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use GRAPH API :

```
`$graphURL = https://graph.facebook.com/$current_user_id/home?access_token=$user_access_token.`
```

You can use curl to get the details .Example curl function is

```
function curl_get_file_contents($URL) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
 $contents = curl_exec($ch);
 $err  = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 curl_close($ch);
$contents=json_decode($contents,true);
 if ($contents) return $contents;
 else return FALSE;
```

}

Ex:-
   $user_home = curl_get_file_contents($graphURL);